# Excel newline (char(10)) copy/paste issue

Tags: excel, ascii, plaintext

I'm trying to use `CHAR(10)` to create some nice formatting for some scripting I am generating, but copying and pasting is not working for me.  I am running Windows 8.1 atm.  Here's a clarifying example.  Using the formula:

```
="hello"&CHAR(10)&"world"
```

I get `hello[newline]world` in Excel.  Copying/pasting into Notepad, I would expect

```
hello
world
```

But when I actually perform that copy/paste, I instead get:

```
helloworld
```

Now, I know that the newline is in there, because if I copy that output *from notepad* into this very window, I get the newline reinserted.  I ultimately need to c/p out from Excel into plaintext with (visible) line breaks.  Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Make sure you have `wrapped text` checked off

Comment: It is, but the issue I'm experiencing is really in Notepad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "newline", in Windows, is typically a carriage return followed by a line feed. Those are two separate character codes: 13 & 10, respectively.

So your formula in Excel would need to be:

```
="hello"&CHAR(13)&CHAR(10)&"world"
```